# extract particular element without namespace using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract only `<b:title1>value of title1</b:title1>` element by using `b:title` as start node in matching. But, in my output, value of `p:number1`, `p:number2`, `p:number3`, `p:number4` has been included in output
xml

```
<page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/">
 <menu>
   <b:title>
        <b:title1>
           value of title1
        </b:title1>
        <b:title2>
           value of title2
        </b:title2>
  </b:title>
 <p:number1>page001</p:number1>
 <p:number2>page002</p:number2>
 <p:number3>page001</p:number3>
 <p:number4>page002</p:number4>
 </menu> 
</page>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b="http://book.com/">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/> 
   <xsl:template match="b:title">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(b:title1)}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="b:title1"/>  
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
   <title1>
      value of title1
   </title1>
    page001
    page002
    page001
    page002
```

Desire output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <b:title1>
      value of title1
  </b:title1>
```